# To find the length of a portion of a side of a triangle given that the triangle is inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

$ABC$ is a triangle inscribed in a circle. $AD, AE$ are straight lines drawn from the vertex A to the base BC parallel to the tangents at B and C respectively. If $AB = 5$ cm, $AC = 6$ cm, and $CE = 9$ cm, then what is the length of $BD$ (in cm)?

I tried using cosine rule. But I am stuck anyways.

Comment: Maybe it will help you solving it but angle BAC is equal to angle OBC and angle OCB, where O is intersection point of tangents. It is because BAC is equal to half the central angle, and OBC and OCB also do. OBC equal to central angle because it is angle between the chord and tangent line ( there is such a property that angle between chord and tangent is equal to half the central angle, which stands on the chord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Rename $E$ and $D$ in text of OP. We see that $a+x=9$.

Since we have $$\angle BDA = \angle BAC$$ wesee that $AC$ is tangent on circle $ABD$ so we have $$CA^2 = CB\cdot CD \implies 36 = 9\cdot a \implies a=4$$

Similary we have $$BA^2 = BE\cdot BC \implies 25 = (a+y)a \implies y=2.25$$

Comment: May I know how ∠BDA=∠BAC and I did not get the next step either "we see that AC is tangent on circle ABD so we have
CA2=CB⋅CD".

Comment: Do you know what is an angle between tangent line and chord?

Comment: No, I am new to this.

Comment: Then I can't help, search google.

Comment: I googled. The angle between chord BC and tangent at B is equal to angle BAC. So , if I am right , is BX = XD? ( where X is point of intersection of tangent at B and AD)

Comment: Yes...............

Comment: So, it follows that triangle  DCA and ACB are similar and hence you got the equation $CA^2=CB*CD$ . Rest of it , I understood.

The only thing I am not able to figure out is , why  BX = XD? ( where X is point of intersection of tangent at B and AD)

Comment: Finally I got it. $AD||$ to tangent at $C$ and $CD$ is the transversal line. Hence angle ADB is equal to angle between chord BC and tangent at C . 

Thanks a lot .